# How can I drop a Memory Optimized Table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, memory-optimized-tables, drop-table

Running SQL Server Standard 2016 SP2-CU1.  I am not as concerned with the In memory Filegroup, but I must be able to drop the table objects? Or possibly rename them?

Running:

```
DROP TABLE [REF].[Work_xxyyzz]
```

Gives:

> Msg 12332, Level 16, State 111, Line 1
>   Database and server triggers on DDL statements CREATE, ALTER and DROP are not supported with memory optimized tables.

There are no user triggers or events on my In Memory Tables.  5 simple tables with primary keys.

There are no dependencies or references to these tables.  They are like temp tables, we name them `Work_xxxyyzz` tables.  However, they do belong to a database schema.

I am fine to keep the filegroup in place for now.  I want to drop these tables in order to create default objects of the same name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a transactional replication trigger that was causing my problem.

[Evan Carroll's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218224/116653) provided the direction to look, [jadarnel27's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218251/116653) provided syntax, and they both helped point me to DDL triggers as the root cause. I needed to execute in the proper database context.

ANSWER:

```
USE [userdb]
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers;

tr_MStran_droptable 18203215    0   DATABASE    0   TR  SQL_TRIGGER 2018-07-19 16:14:05.537 2018-09-21 10:32:34.580 1   1   0   0
....

DISABLE TRIGGER tr_MStran_droptable ON DATABASE;

DROP TABLE [REF].[Work_xxyyzz];
```

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the restrictions pointed out in [Evan's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/218224/6141), there are a number of other things that can prevent dropping tables.  Most of them are similar to the restrictions on normal disk-based tables, and you should see them called out in your error message.

For instance, if I have an in-memory table referenced by a natively-compiled (schemabound) stored procedure, I'll get this error if I drop the table:

> Cannot DROP TABLE 'YourTable' because it is being referenced by object 'sp_YourStoredProc'.

The solution in that case is to drop the stored proc first, and then drop the table.

---

The error message you're getting indicates that there is a server or database level *DDL trigger.*  You'll need to disable or drop those triggers in order to drop the in-memory table.  You can find any such triggers by running these queries:

```
USE [master];
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.server_triggers;

USE [YourDatabaseName];
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers;
```

You should look into what these triggers are doing (auditing, perhaps?).  If it's safe to do so, consider disabling them with the [`DISABLE TRIGGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/disable-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement, then dropping your table, then using [`ENABLE TRIGGER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/enable-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to turn the triggers back on.

Note that server and database-scoped DDL triggers are different from object level DML triggers (which you mentioned that you checked for and there are none).

Answer (score 3):

Just use `DROP TABLE`, there is [one caveat,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/transact-sql-constructs-not-supported-by-in-memory-oltp?view=sql-server-2017#memory-optimized-tables)

> Memory-optimized tables and natively compiled stored procedures cannot be created or dropped if there is a server or database trigger for that DDL operation. Remove the server and database triggers on `CREATE`/`DROP TABLE` and `CREATE`/`DROP PROCEDURE`.

Make sure there are no DDL event notifications,

> Memory-optimized tables and natively compiled stored procedures cannot be created or dropped if there is a server or database event notification for that DDL operation. Remove the server and database event notifications on `CREATE TABLE` or `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE` or `DROP PROCEDURE`.